# Android implementing sliding tabs?

Tags: java, android, tabs

I am using a library to add sliding tabs https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip but I run into problems with the `Adapter`.

Below you see `TestAdapter` I am not sure how to implement it.

```
  // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
  ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

  // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
  PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
  tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

I am working inside MainActivity and I have added to the xml

```
 <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Obviously I need to now build an Adapter, so I have looked through the examples and tried to implement https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/SuperAwesomeCardFragment.java

I am not sure if thats what I need and it is not an adapter, so how do I create a simple Adapter for this case?

Comment: Look at MyPagerAdapter: https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: Sweet thanks about to take a look! :)

Comment: Oh yeah I actually implemented that, but then that forced me to use the Fragment, and then I fixed all the issues android studio was giving me and the app crashed. I think I should have debugged better, but is there a way to keep the Fragment code to a minimum? So I can wrap my head around it better?

Comment: For example Butterknife (I should probably look into it), gave me issues so I just commented it out, and I think thats why my code crashed.

Comment: Oh I see I can just use it with gradle `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'`

Comment: So I think I got it to work. But it is not sliding do I need to build my own ViewPager or does your library do that? Thanks for this library BTW